# Synchronously iterate a flat array and 2d array, transpose the rows, then perform division

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, transpose, division

I need to loop over a 2d array, access its columnar data and perform division against the corresponding value in a flat array.

The flat array:

```
$array1 = [
    'maxwater' => 1,
    'maxfodder' => 2,
    'maxmob' => 3,
    'maxalt' => 4,
    'maxhum' => 5,
    'mintemp' => 6
];
```

The 2d array:

```
$array2 = [
    [2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2],
    [3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3],
    [4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3],
    [3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
];
```

What I want to do here is only to divide each column in `$array2` by the respective number in `$array1`.

For example,

- the first value in `$array1` (`maxwater`) has a value of `1`.  This number should be used to divide each value in the first column of `$array2` (`2`, `3`, `4`, `3`, `1`).
- Then the next value in `$array2` (`maxfodder`) is `2`. The second column values in `$array2` (`3`, `2`, `1`, `4`, `2`) should be divided by `2`.
- This process should be repeated for all of the columns in `$array2`.

And I already try using this code, but it generates an error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Livestockmapping\dsssawprocess.php on line 42
> Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\Livestockmapping\dsssawprocess.php on line 42
> 0

Code:

```
$yaxis = sizeof($array2);
$xaxis = max(array_map('count', $array2));

echo $xaxis;
echo $yaxis;

//normalization
for($i=0; $i < $xaxis; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j < $yaxis; $j++)
    {
        $c1norm = round($array2[$i][$j]/$array1[$j]);
        echo $c1norm;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to find the correct way to do this?

edit:
My second coding attempt:

```
foreach($array1 as $v){
    echo (array_sum(array_column($array2, $v - 1)) / $v) . "<br />";
}
```

It provides a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 3.6666666666667
    [3] => 3.5
    [4] => 1.4
    [5] => 2.3333333333333
)
```

But what I want is to divide every column value in `$array2` like this:

```
2 / 1 = 2
3 / 1 = 3
4 / 1 = 4
3 / 1 = 3
1 / 1 = 1

3 / 2 = 2
2 / 2 = 1
1 / 2 = 1
4 / 2 = 2
2 / 2 = 1

4 / 3 = 1
1 / 3 = 0
2 / 3 = 1
2 / 3 = 1
2 / 3 = 1
```

...and so on.

Comment: Please show us the array structure with `print_r($yourArray);` for both arrays.

Comment: $array1 = ( [maxwater] => 1 [maxfodder] => 2 [maxmob] => 3 [maxalt] => 4 [maxhum] => 5 [mintemp] => 6 )

Comment: `array1` has numbers `(1-6)`, `array2` has only `5` rows, which row on `array2` do you divide the last number `6` inside array1

Comment: no, i mean array1 will divide each column of array2, not the row of array2, array2 got 6 columns.

Comment: would you please print_r the $array2 ?! and after dividing what is the expected result?

Comment: @Atiqur check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're dividing the elements based of the matrix of `$array2`.

Include the `for` loop of the `$array1` (each of it) and apply it on each column of `$array2`

```
$array2[$j][$i] 
        ^ column first
```

Example:

```
// $array1 = array_values($array1); numeric index conversion
$c = count($array1);
$xaxis = sizeof($array2);
$yaxis = max(array_map('count', $array2));

// normalization
for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < ($yaxis - 1); $j++) {
        $c1norm = round($array2[$j][$i] / $array1[$i]);
        echo $c1norm;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1e8O6)

Comment: $array1[$i] will be empty isn't it ? check the $array1 structure

Comment: @Atiqur example here uses `array(1, - 6)` which was the previous post, the OP changed it, anyway, i'l just add `array_values` in the mix to reformat the whole array indexing on `$array1`

Comment: @Ghost hello, your code is just like what i want, but i keep getting the same error like what i already mentioned above. :)

Comment: @aureliadsp check out this demo, if this is the exact array structure that you have, it should work just fine https://3v4l.org/KIonZ

Answer (score 0):

```
$indexLevelOne = count($array2);
$indexLevelTwo = count($array2[0]);

// normalization
$k=0;
foreach($array1 as $v){
    for($j=0; $j<$indexLevelTwo; $j++){
        if($j != $k) continue;
        for($i=0; $i<$indexLevelOne; $i++){
            $c1norm = round($array2[$i][$j] / $v);
            echo $array2[$i][$j] . " / " . $v . " = " . $c1norm, "\n";
        }
       echo "\n\n"; 

    }
    echo "\n\n";
    $k++;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I'll demonstrate a modern, functional-style technique leveraging nest `array_map()` calls to synchronously iterate the two array and transpose the multidimensional array.

By using the spread operator while passing second array into `array_map()` then again using the spread operator to receive the data, "transposition" occurs -- in other words, a column of data becomes a row of data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/erA1N))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($divisor, ...$column) => array_map(
            fn($v) => round($v / $divisor),
            $column
        ),
        array_values($array1),
        ...$array2
    )
);
```